# Copy Objects using DigitalOcean Spaces

Tags: java, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I'm currently using Digital Ocean with the Amazon S3 SDK, and I'm able to upload and delete files programmatically. However, copying objects seem to be a big issue.

First of all, my list of buckets always return 0 results:

```
s3Client.listBuckets() // 0 results
```

Second, I have an object called `company__1/tempom81p2epoksju921ntk/CLASSIFICATION/127a58b2_dd14_4851_88f2_99d28f849191.jpeg` in a space called  `my_do_space`. If I want to copy this object, inside the same space, how the right code would look like? I have tried the following:

```
s3Client.copyObject("my_do_space","company__1/tempom81p2epoksju921ntk/CLASSIFICATION/127a58b2_dd14_4851_88f2_99d28f849191.jpeg", "my_do_space", "company__1/somenewthing/CLASSIFICATION/test.jpeg");
```

I have also tried every possible combination, and none of them seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out that my credentials were wrong, I was using the following:

```
digitalocean:
  spaces:
    endpoint: https://my_bucket.sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

And for some reason, I was able to correctly upload/delete files from it

When I changed my credentials to:

```
digitalocean:
  spaces:
    endpoint: https://sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

and them specifying the bucket via code:

```
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("my_bucket", key, fileToUpload)
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

I was able to correctly copy it using the code in my questions